# Assign an action to a simple button

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to render a simple button with a submission handler. I tried two  methods, and this is the code I used.

### First method

#### mymodule.module

```
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  $type = $entity->bundle();
  if ($type == "property") {
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/custom_styling';
    $build['mymodule_btn'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Generate PDF',
      '#submit' => ['mymodule_generate_pdf'],
      '#weight' => -1,
    ];
   }
}

function mymodule_generate_pdf() {
  // ...
}
```

### Second method

#### mymodule.module

```
function mymodule_entity_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  $type = $entity->bundle();
  if ($type == "property") {
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/custom_styling';
     return \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\MyModule\Form\MyModuleForm::class);
  }
}
```

#### MyModuleForm.php

```
namespace Drupal\MyModule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfigFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Generate the button.
 */
class MyModuleForm extends ConfigFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['mymodule_btn'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Generate PDF',
      //'#submit' => ['mymodule_pdf_generate_pdf'],
      '#weight' => -1,
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // ...
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // ...
    \Drupal::formBuilder()->submitForm('mymodule_form', $form_state);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function getEditableConfigNames() {
  }
}
```

The first method generates the button, but the submission handler is not executed. The second method doesn't even generate the button.

How can I fix the code I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Method 2 you want to add the form as an element in the $build array.

Should be something like this:

```
$build['my_form'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\myModule\Form\myModuleForm::class);
```

Also you don't need to return anything, `$build` is passed by reference, so anything you add to it will stick.

Comment: It works beautifully, but now my question is: how I can pass $entity so that I can use the entity's properties?

Comment: @Kartagis – Please ask a new question instead of broadening this one.